# Do Apex Schedules have Metadata?

Tags: scheduled-apex, metadata

I'm writing my first scheduled Apex for an internal organization. We do all of our development using `sfdx` and scratch orgs, merging into production using GitHub actions linked to the `main` branch.

In my scratch org I've created a schedule on an Apex class for 1 am every morning. When I try to pull source, nothing is retrieved from the scratch org.

Are Apex schedules not part of an org's metadata? Do I need to simply set up the schedule once we've deployed this new class to prod?

Comment: There is an object, [CronTrigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm) along with other associated data, but it isn't something you can pull and push with sfdx. You can, however, easily run anonymous apex via sfdx to check if your scheduled job is or is not running and to start it if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex Schedule class are part of "Apex Class" metadata itself. Once you deploy the Schedule Class to Prod you need to schedule it through anonymous code or from schedule apex from Setup -> Apex Class -> Schedule Apex.

Comment: It's great to see this flurry of helpful answers from you after so long of, I assume, lurking. I just wanted to let you know that I edited this answer to remove your suggestion for folks to upvote it if it is helpful. While folks *should* upvote if it's a good/helpful answer, and questioners definitely *should* accept the answer that gave the solution/found the issue/was the most helpful, it is frowned upon here on SFSE for answerers to request those things.

Comment: I assume he's used to posting questions on Salesforce's own forums, where I've noticed it's quite common for answers to request the original poster accept the answer as the correct one. But yea, I don't think I've seen that on any of the SO sites.